# HTTP Status codes symbol sequences

Tags: python, http, python-requests

During exploration of the Requests—HTTP library for Python `status_codes.py` [module](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py), I found four symbol sequences corresponding to certain HTTP status codes (see below).

`\\o/` for 200 at [line 13](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py#L13):
`200: ('ok', 'okay', 'all_ok', 'all_okay', 'all_good', '\\o/', '✓'),`

`\\o-` for 301 at [line 26](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py#L26):
`301: ('moved_permanently', 'moved', '\\o-'),`

`-o-` for 404 at [line 41](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py#L41):
`404: ('not_found', '-o-'),`

`/o\\` for 500 at [line 72](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py#L72):
`500: ('internal_server_error', 'server_error', '/o\\', '✗'),`

Which history of that sequences? Where they are used and what for?

Comment: They definitely look like aircraft marshalling signals `-o-` - hands to the side, `\o/` - hands up, `/o\\` - hands down.

Comment: FWIW these are not part of the HTTP spec... Looks like some kind of programmer's joke to me (might be part of an easter egg ?)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you're right. I wrote to Kenneth Reitz, author of the Requests library, and he respond that they are fun easter eggs. But  what are they mean? Maybe teivaz is right too?

Comment: teivaz is definitely right about what those smileys represent (hands to the sides etc). Don't know whether they come from aircraft signals but they sure were of common use in the usenet days...